# Oracle error ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Tags: python, oracle, integration

Why am I getting this error in Oracle DB?

cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

```
cur.execute("select jobid, jobname, technology, skillset, salary, minimumexp from job where technology=:technology or int(salary)>=:int(salary) or int(minimumexp)<=int(minimumexp)",{"technology":technology,"int(salary)":int(salary),"int(minimumexp)":int(minimumexp)})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that `INT` function is valid in this context; at least, it does nothing in Oracle. Unless I'm wrong, it converts *float* numbers into *integers*. If that's so, try with the `TRUNC` function instead, as Python's `INT` cuts off decimals.

Besides, it seems that you used the colon sign (which represents a *parameter*, right?) on the wrong place (should be in front of the parameter name, not the `INT` (or `TRUNC`) function).

For example:

```
No : or int(salary)   >= :int(salary)
Yes: or trunc(salary) >= trunc(:salary)
```